# How can I get the elements of an array without the brackets and no line break?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js, line-breaks

What I want:

```
var word = ["happy", "penguin", "sword"]

message.channel.send(word)

//prints 
"happy", "penguin", "sword"
```

What actually happens:

```
var word = ["happy", "penguin", "sword"]

message.channel.send(word)
//prints
happy
penguin
sword
```

This is on discord.js, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the array into a string, and then send that instead.

```js
const word = ["happy", "penguin", "sword"];

const str = `"${word.join('", "')}"`;

console.log(str);
```

Additional documentation

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: And what if you have an array like this? `["text\"moretext", "something"]` You will get `"text"moretext", "something"`

Comment: I base my answers on the evidence in the question only to keep them as succinct as possible. If I wrote about every variation of the data I could conceive of I'd be here all day, and I've some gardening to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use JSON.stringify to map all array values:

```js
const word = ["happy", "penguin", "sword", "the \"craziest\" thing ever"];

const str = word.map(w => JSON.stringify(w)).join(", ");

console.log(str);
```

If you don't know [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it is a really helpful function that loops over every value and returns an array with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var word = ["happy", "penguin", "sword"]

word.forEach(el => console.log(el))
/*
happy
penguin
sword
*/

console.log(word.toString())
// happy,penguin,sword

console.log(`"${word.join('", "')}"`)
// "happy", "penguin", "sword"
```